# Pipe que busque un valor que pueda ser date o null en Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, null, pipe, angular10

Hola a todos soy nuevo con Angular y mi duda es la siguiente, tengo una tabla con datos uno de esos campos se llama Fecha de Asignacion el cual almacena una fecha o un valor Null, entonces al aplicar pipe los demas campos los trabaja bien el buscador pero el campo Fecha_asignacion al tener elementos Null me tira error

> "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null"

como podria dejar que mi pipe al transformar acepte los valores Null.

Aqui esta el pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'asig'
})
export class AsigPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any , args?: any ): any {    
    if (!value)return null;
    if (!args)return value;    
    const resultPosts = [];   
    for(const assignment of value){
      if(assignment.IdAsignacion.toString().toLowerCase().includes(args.toLowerCase())
      || assignment.NombreUnidad.toLowerCase().includes(args.toLowerCase()) 
      || assignment.NombreEmpleado.toString().toLowerCase().includes(args.toLowerCase())      
      || assignment.Fecha_Registro.toString().toLowerCase().includes(args.toLowerCase())
      || assignment.Fecha_Asignacion.toString().toLowerCase().includes(args.toLowerCase()) //Este tiene valores Null
      || assignment.NombreEstado.toLowerCase().includes(args.toLowerCase()) 
       )
      {
        resultPosts.push(assignment);      };
      };
    return resultPosts;    
  }

}
```

Aqui esta el html

```
<tr *ngFor="let assignment of assignments | asig :filter4 | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: page }">
                <th>{{assignment.IdAsignacion}}</th>
                <td>{{assignment.NombreUnidad}}</td>  
                <td>{{assignment.NombreEmpleado}}</td>  
                <td>{{assignment.Fecha_Registro}}</td>
                <td>{{assignment.Fecha_Asignacion || 'N/A' }}</td>
                <td>{{assignment.NombreEstado}}</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operaciones que te pueden resultar de utilidad:

- [Logical nullish assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)
- [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)
- [Optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

En este caso usando *Nullish coalescing operator* tu pipe quedaría así

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'asig'
})
export class AsigPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any , args?: any ): any {    
    if (!value)return null;
    if (!args)return value;    
    const resultPosts = [];   
    for(const assignment of value){
      if(assignment.IdAsignacion.toString().toLowerCase().includes(args.toLowerCase())
      || assignment.NombreUnidad.toLowerCase().includes(args.toLowerCase()) 
      || assignment.NombreEmpleado.toString().toLowerCase().includes(args.toLowerCase())      
      || assignment.Fecha_Registro.toString().toLowerCase().includes(args.toLowerCase())
      || (assignment.Fecha_Asignacion ?? '').toString().toLowerCase().includes(args.toLowerCase()) //Este tiene valores Null
      || assignment.NombreEstado.toLowerCase().includes(args.toLowerCase()) 
       )
      {
        resultPosts.push(assignment);      };
      };
    return resultPosts;    
  }
```

**NOTA:** como buena práctica, podrías usar este operando con todas las propiedades del objeto a la hora de comparar para asegurarte de no tener errores

Comment: Muchas gracias enserio, soluciono mi problema y a la vez aprendi una nueva practica.